# Randomizing time zone in Rails with Zonebie

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, cucumber

I'm using [Zonebie](https://github.com/highgroove/zonebie) to randomize the time zone in my tests. It's all working fine for my rspec tests, but I'm having an issue with my cucumber tests. It works by selecting a random timezone from `ActiveSupport` and setting `Time.zone`. I've [followed the readme](https://github.com/highgroove/zonebie#cucumber) and added `Zonebie.set_random_timezone` to a support file `features/support/zonbie.rb`.

If I put a `debugger` statement in my steps, and I print `Time.zone`, it produces the correct randomized timezone.  However, if I put a `debuggger` statement in a model function, it prints the default time zone as set up in my `config/application.rb`.

Is Time.zone being reset somewhere or does the change go out of scope somehow? Any ideas?

**NB**: I'm also using the [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem if that has any implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack solution, which was to set `Time.zone_default` instead of `Time.zone` to the random timezone. I might send a pull request to the zonebie gem maintainers.